# Can't Create Scratch Orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode, sfdx-falcon, sfdx-plugin

[image]My vscode version is 1.30.1 and my sfdx version is sfdx-cli/6.44.0-dead729fb5 (darwin-x64) node-v8.9.4. I created 3-4 dev hug orgs and tried to create a scratch org from it but it is not working. I am keep getting the following error when I run the create command not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias LWC --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername
```

ERROR:  Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token.

Comment: Have you authorized your dev-hub as `sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub` ?

Comment: Yes I authorised my dev hub org sucessfully

Comment: When you run force:org:list, do you still see your DevHub as connected ?

Comment: You should use `--setdefaultdevhubusername` to set up your Dev Hub, and `--setdefaultusername` to set up your default scratch org. You are misusing it.
Correct it to the proper way and try again.
Let us know afterwards